# CloudKit handling of ChangeTokenExpired error

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, cloudkit

From the Apple `CKErrorCode` documentation, it says ["The previousServerChangeToken value is too old and the client must re-sync from scratch."](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckerror.code/1515263-changetokenexpired?changes=latest_beta)  Does anyone know exactly what they mean by "re-sync from scratch?"  I interpret it as send everything locally up to iCloud, then fetch everything from the server back down.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is when using `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation`. If you use this operation and it is created with a specific change token, then you might get that error. If you do get the error, simply create and run another `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` but pass `nil` to the `init(previousServerChangeToken:)` initializer.

It's possible you will get some results you've already processed in the past. Your code needs to deal with that possibility.